# Error de symfony the class "App\Entity\Users" must implement "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface"

Tags: php, symfony, orm

recibo este error al introducir el comando `php bin/console make:auth` y posteriormente, introducir el nombre del controlador.

He estado informándome acerca de la implementación de Userinterface, y he tratado de cambiar el  `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsersRepository")` por  `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface")`

También he intentado importar `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` mediante `use`.

¿Me pueden indicar cual puede ser el error?
Esta es la clase Users tal y como me la genera el make:entity (excepto algunos parametros como unique que he agregado yo)
<?php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UsersRepository::class)
 */
class Users
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=75)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=true)
 */
private $created_at;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=true)
 */
private $updated_at;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
{
    return $this->created_at;
}

public function setCreatedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at): self
{
    $this->created_at = $created_at;

    return $this;
}

public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
{
    return $this->updated_at;
}

public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at): self
{
    $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

    return $this;
}
```

}

Si necesitan algo más no duden en pedirmelo, un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta poner el `implements UserInterface` en la clase Users.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface {}
```

Como se indica en la guía de symfony ([Guía Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-create-your-user-class)):

> The only rule about your User class is that it must implement Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface.

La otra alternativa es en lugar de usar el `make:entity`, que te crea una entity estandar, en este caso deberias usar el `make:user` incluido en el MakerBundle, que te crea todo lo necesitas para gestionar users.

Te dejo aquí la demo de symfony para que te hagas una idea de como podría quedar la entity User. [Link](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/main/src/Entity/User.php)